# List Sorting Algorithm in Python does not run

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-module

I am making a module called "dumbstuff" just as a hobby and can't seem to identify the problem.The function is set to take in a list and an operator to sort the list in ascending order or descending order. When I run the function, a blank screen appears, I've been at it for a while and cannot figure out what's wrong.

Here's the sorting function in the "dumbstuff" module:

```
def sortlist(rawlist: list, operator: str, ifprint: bool):
    looped = 0
    done = 0
    index = 0
    sortedList = []

    while (done == 0):
        index = 0
        looped = 0
        
        #ascending sort
        if (operator == "<"):
            while (index < len(rawlist) - 1):
                if (rawlist[index] > rawlist[index + 1]):
                    temp = rawlist[index]
                    rawlist[index] = rawlist[index + 1]
                    rawlist[index + 1] = temp
                    looped += 1
            if (looped == 0): done = 1
            sortedList = rawlist
        #descending sort
        if (operator == ">"):
            while (index < len(rawlist) - 1):
                if (rawlist[index] < rawlist[index + 1]):
                    temp = rawlist[index + 1]
                    rawlist[index + 1] = rawlist[index]
                    rawlist[index] = temp
                    looped += 1
            if (looped == 0): done += 1
            sortedList = rawlist

    if (ifprint == True):
        print(sortedList)
```

and here is the code I am trying to run it through, it creates an array of 20 random integers,

```
import random
import dumbstuff as ds

array = []
index = 0

while (index < 20):
    array.append(random.randint(0, 20))
    index += 1

ds.sortlist(array, "<", ifprint=True)
input()
```

However, the code appears to never return and also never outputs anything to the screen.

Comment: Have to attempted any debug to see how far the code is getting?

Comment: yep, thanks for pointing it out, cant believe I missed something so small

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to increment `index` somewhere in your code.

Perhaps you could replace the while loop with a for loop.

```
        #ascending sort
        if (operator == "<"):
          for index in range(len(rawlist) - 1): # Here.
            while (index < len(rawlist) - 1):
```

With this change, it appears to work https://repl.it/repls/SilentDelectablePrinter.